# Clean urls - auto path alias - how to remove accents (Á É Ó Í Ñ ) from the urls?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases, uri

I´m using Drupal 7.9 and pathauto 7.x-1.0-rc2

I want to remove the accents from the paths and replace them with normal letters

```
Á=A
É=E
Ó=O
Í=I
Ñ=N
```

etc.

I'm using a taxonomy field type and node title to build the path:

```
[node:field_provincia]/[node:title]
```

resulting into e.g. *ávila/mérida*

Does pathauto have some kind of hooks that I could use to apply this function?

```
function removeAccents($str)
{
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ');
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}
```

Comment: Relevant issue in [pathauto's queue](https://drupal.org/comment/7747561#comment-7747561).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you seen [transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module ?  The project summary says it could be used with pathauto 2.x to use transliteration for URLs.

Comment: This is exactly what I use and it works beautifully.  I had yet another issue with "ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ" while using Drupal's mail function as well and Transliteration cleaned those up too.

Comment: But the problem is that it changes all language chars in URL to English ones which look weird. For example רשימה של מדינות בעולם in Hebrew becomes /rshymh-shl-mdynvt-bvlm. The OP is asking how to remove only accented chars.

Comment: @AgA you can fine tune what it transliterates by hacking the files that come with the module (or overriding, it's OOP if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to perform this remains **[transliteration](http://drupal.org/project/transliteration)** module.

To answer specifically to "*Does pathauto have some kind of hooks that I could use to apply this function*",
you can use **[hook_pathauto_alias_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7)** :

```
function YOURMODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, &$context){
  $alias = removeAccents($alias);
}

function removeAccents($str){
  $a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ');
  $b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o');
  return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}
```

Just **adapt** `removeAccents()` **to your specific language needs**... You'll find many functions trying to list all kind of accents, see [Remove diacritics from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string) i.e., but I'm afraid none is universal.

There is also an **elegant way to transliterate, using [php iconv function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)**, which removes most of the diacritics. If you are getting question-marks in output, it might be convenient to setlocale first. In context  :

```
function YOURMODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, &$context){
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'es_ES');//Spanish Spain i.e
  $alias = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $alias);
}
```

EDIT : after reading some comments, I found useful to add this:

- **D8** : transliteration functionality is now part of Drupal 8 core, use [hook_transliteration_overrides_alter(&$overrides, $langcode)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_transliteration_overrides_alter/8) if yo need some custom overrides.
- **D7** : seems that transliteration next release 7.x-4.x will be a backport of the codebase from D8 core, including the above hook. In the meanwhile, **transliteration module supports language-specific variations** (see [Language-specific replacements](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/transliteration) how-to at the bottom of the doc page). And a couple of relevant issues : [Add hook to allow customization of character mappings](https://drupal.org/node/1943290), [alter hook for transliteration_clean_filename](https://drupal.org/node/1919874).

Comment: Thanks .. are those the only accented chars in the world? Do you have working examples of the iconv use case?

Comment: In pathauto settings I've added Â,Ã,Ä,À,Á,Å,Æ,Ç,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ð,Ñ,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,Ø,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,Þ,ß,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,æ,ç,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ð,ñ,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,ø,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,þ,ÿ, but don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465990/how-to-handle-diacritics-accents-when-rewriting-pretty-urls/466117#466117 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string

Comment: @AgA I edited the answer to reflect your comments. Pathauto settings is not the right place to specify accents to clean, as the lone text field is 'Strings to Remove'. You'd better try hook_pathauto_alias_alter() if module transliteration doesn't fit your needs. Clean url is a wide subject if you consider all alphabets, Hindi, Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew...

Comment: I always use the transliteration module, works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

As per Kojo's suggestions and and source from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php -- I'm using this code which seems to be working fine:

```
function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, &$context) {        
    removeAccents($alias);        
}

function removeAccents(&$str) {
    $unwanted_array = array('Š' => 'S', 'š' => 's', 'Ž' => 'Z', 'ž' => 'z', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'A', 'Ç' => 'C', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E',
        'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U',
        'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Þ' => 'B', 'ß' => 'Ss', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a', 'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'a', 'ç' => 'c',
        'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ð' => 'o', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o',
        'ö' => 'o', 'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y', 'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'b', 'ÿ' => 'y',
        'G' => 'G', 'I' => 'I', 'S' => 'S', 'g' => 'g', 'i' => 'i', 's' => 's', 'ü' => 'u',
        'a' => 'a', 'A' => 'A', '?' => 's', '?' => 'S', '?' => 't', '?' => 'T'
    );
    $str = strtr($str, $unwanted_array);

}
```

I've added Turkish and Romanian chars too as in the post comments.

I don't want to use iconv as suggested by Kojo mainly because locale will need to be set and there is added burden to coin the locale string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathauto_cleanstring() for remove the accents character from URL.

```
function MYMODULE_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, &$context) {
  if (isset($context['data']['node'])) {
    // Include the pathauto module.
    module_load_include('module', 'pathauto');
    // Clean up a string segment to be used in an URL alias.
    $alias = pathauto_cleanstring(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $alias));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your module but its not working

Comment: @Yuri Have you installed transliteration module?